Flask won't recognize token_verification_loader package
According to the docs for token_verification_loader, I need to use:
from flask_jwt_extended import token_verification_loader

However, I noticed that I get the error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'token_verification_loader' from 'flask_jwt_extended'

while:
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required

seems to work as expected.
All the articles I've found refer to breaking changes prior to version 4.0.0. However, when I execute pip freeze, I clearly see that I'm using a more recent version:
aniso8601==9.0.1  
click==8.1.8  
colorama==0.4.6  
Flask==2.2.2  
Flask-JWT-Extended==4.7.1  
Flask-RESTful==0.3.10  
gunicorn==23.0.0  
itsdangerous==2.2.0  
Jinja2==3.1.5  
MarkupSafe==3.0.2  
packaging==24.2  
PyJWT==2.10.1  
pytz==2024.2  
six==1.17.0  
Werkzeug==2.2.2

I tried reinstalling everything, per How to deal with the flask_jwt_extended import error?, but ended with the same version as before, still unable to import the function.

The docs you link to say no such thing. That's a method, on JWTManager.

@jonrsharpe Ah, I see... That wasn't obvious to me at all... But it's a perfect explanation of why I can't import it.
